# how do i count the number of data in a column for each month using a start and end date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with similar information and i want to extract the data like this when a user selects a start date '2015-01-22' and end date '2015-07-31' . 
The result should look like this.

```
Month        Total Quantity    
January: 8
February: 6
March: 0
April: 0
May: 2
June: 18
July: 6
```

Here's a sample query and fiddle

```
CREATE TABLE orders
(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  order_date DATE,
  product_id INT,
  quantity INT,
  customer_id INT
);
INSERT INTO orders (order_date, product_id, quantity, customer_id)
  VALUES
  ('2015-01-01', 1, 2, 123),
  ('2015-01-06', 3, 6, 123),
  ('2015-02-14', 2, 4, 123),
  ('2015-02-15', 2, 2, 123),
  ('2015-05-16', 1, 1, 456),
  ('2015-05-17', 1, 1, 456),
  ('2015-06-18', 1, 5, 789),
  ('2015-06-18', 3, 7, 123),
  ('2015-06-10', 3, 6, 123),
  ('2015-07-13', 1, 5, 456),
  ('2015-07-14', 1, 1, 456);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01ac19/1

The results should be the total number of quantity of Orders per month

Comment: ok, but what do you tried so far? (show us your not working query ;) )

Comment: can put `monthname(DATE(order_date)) as dateinfo`. this by itself wont get you the zeros though

Comment: Ah right the 0s, didn't even think of that

Comment: Actually, you have a larger problem here - what happens if the user chooses a date not at month start/end?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse, thanks for pointing out the BETWEEN issue. What's your recommended solution?

Comment: @phil - for everything except an explicit integral count ("you have 4 of this" - that, and possibly one optimization case for distances), an inclusive bound on both edges is wrong.  This has to do with how numbers are represented in math in general - how many 9's are there after a decimal place before it changes (3.99999... to 4, say)?  The correct way to look at it is "it stops being value A when it becomes value B": how long were you 1 year old?   Until you became 2 (your second birthday happened).  Forget `BETWEEN` exists, and specify your ranges explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, what you <strike>want</strike> NEED is known as a "Calendar table".  They are, hands down, the most useful Analysis table you can make.  Their individual definition and data fill varies, and won't be covered here, but for our purposes, we'll use the following minimum definition:

```
CREATE TABLE Calendar (calendarDate DATE PRIMARY KEY,
                       year INTEGER,
                       month INTEGER
                       dayOfMonth INTEGER);
```

... and it's filled with data like you expect (insert every single date from when your business started, to a reasonable point in the future).  You also want indices on this - *lots* of indices.

Next, you need to consider something important about databases: they can't use indices if function output is used as criteria.  Basically, if it's not in the `SELECT` clause, using a function (even via some implicit casts) makes your query slower.  So, doing things like `YEAR(order_date)` should be avoided.
How then do we aggregate by things like year or month?  Via ranges queries.  If the database has an index, it's pretty cheap for it to look up the start and end of a range (and nicely parallelizable, too).  In our case, the range is `>= startOfMonth` to `< startOfNextMonth`.  We can now build an in-process range table:

```
SELECT year, month, 
       calendarDate AS monthStart, 
       calendarDate + INTERVAL 1 MONTH AS nextMonthStart
FROM Calendar
WHERE dayOfMonth = 1
      AND calendarDate >= :queryStartRange
      AND calendarDate < :queryEndRange
```

... where the `:` is denoting start-of-month values, which is left as an exercise for the reader.

Now, remember how I said "no functions"?  `calendarDate + INTERVAL 1 MONTH` actually counts.  However, it's not going to matter here; the resulting table is so small (just 12 rows per year!) that good RDBMSs can place the contents in memory for faster results (because it would take longer to hit just the index).

Now that we have our range-query table, we can join it to the `Orders` ("fact") table;

```
SELECT DRange.year, DRange.month, SUM(Orders.quantity) AS total_quantity
FROM (SELECT year, month, 
             calendarDate AS monthStart, 
             calendarDate + INTERVAL 1 MONTH AS nextMonthStart
      FROM Calendar
      WHERE dayOfMonth = 1
            AND calendarDate >= :queryStartRange
            AND calendarDate < :queryEndRange) AS DRange
JOIN Orders
  ON Orders.order_date >= DRange.monthStart
     AND Orders.order_date < DRange.nextMonthStart
GROUP BY DRange.year, DRange.month
ORDER BY DRange.year, DRange.month
```

<kbd>[Example Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f382b/9/0)</kbd>
(fun trick: using `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN` will net you null-quantity rows if a month has no orders - like for March and April in your example data)

So what does this get us?  Range-query access at the base data, which will make for a faster query.  If, for some reason, `order_date` gets turned into a timestamp, the query is completely safe - we'll correctly get all orders, and put them in the proper months.

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me on the benefit of calendar tables. I did some research and now understand it better. Your answer worked perfectly well for my use case. cheers! –

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(DATE(order_date)) AS dateinfo, SUM(quantity) AS total_sales
FROM orders
GROUP BY dateinfo
```

Comment: Fails if the user selects more than one year (probable that the users would want them separated by year), will not use indices.

Comment: @Mukesh, thanks for your response. it helped me a lot. i extended your answer to enable me get a restricted date SELECT MONTHNAME(DATE(order_date)) AS dateinfo, SUM(quantity) AS total_sales
FROM orders WHERE order_date BETWEEN '2015-05-01' AND '2015-06-30'
GROUP BY dateinfo

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse . Thanks for highlighting the flaw.How do i extend Mukesh's answer to cover multiple years? i.e if 2014-06-30 - 2015-06-30 . when i tried to query multiple years,it simply adds all months rather than separate by year

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bded5e/1 . the query needs to separate the answers by year because, if 2014 & 2015 are selected, all values for the month is summed without regard for the year. "see june" in the fiddle. it sums data for June 2014 & June 2015

Comment: SELECT MONTHNAME(DATE(order_date)) AS dateinfo, SUM(quantity) AS total_sales
FROM orders WHERE order_date > '2014-06-30' and order_date< '2015-06-30'
GROUP BY dateinfo